# How to prevent some assemblies to be version-changed with Assembly-Info-NetFramework in an Azure devop pipeline

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops, continuous-integration

We have a big solution that we update the file version within our build pipeline on azure devop:

```
  - task: Assembly-Info-NetFramework@2
    inputs:
      Path: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
      FileNames: |
        **\AssemblyInfo.cs
      InsertAttributes: true
      FileEncoding: 'auto'
      WriteBOM: false
      VersionNumber: ${{parameters.version}}.$(buildNumber)
      FileVersionNumber: ${{parameters.version}}.$(buildNumber)
      InformationalVersion: ${{parameters.version}}.$(buildNumber)
      LogLevel: 'verbose'
      FailOnWarning: false
      Company: 'Some company'
```

The problem is that a few project(4 out of the 450+) needs to keep their current file version, because they are called by a third party executable(DCOM stuff) that search for a specific assembly name and version.

Is there a way to provide an exception for a few project name? How would you proceed?

I've looked here: https://github.com/BMuuN/vsts-assemblyinfo-task/wiki/Task-Parameters-&-Build-Yaml
But I don't see anything for an exception?

Comment: try one of the exclusion patterns described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops#exclude-pattern-examples
e.g.
    FileNames: |
        ** \AssemblyInfo.cs
        !project1 \\**